# Optimization of search function MySQL or PHP wise

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, optimization

After running a few test I realized that my search method does not perform very well if some words of the query is short (2~3 letters).

The way I made the search is by making a MySQL query for every words in the string the visitor entered and then filtering result from each word to see if every words had that result. Once one result has been returned for all words its a match and il show that result to the visitor.

But I was wondering if that's an effective way to do it. Is there any better way while keeping the same functionality ?

Currently the code I have takes about .7Sec making MySQL queries. And the rest of the stuff is under .1Sec.
Normally I would not care much about my search taking .7Sec, But Id like to create a "LiveSearch" and is critical that it loads faster than that.

Here is my code

```
    public static function Search($Query){
        $Querys = explode(' ',$Query);
        foreach($Querys as $Query)
        {
            $MatchingRow = \Database\dbCon::$dbCon -> prepare("
                SELECT
                    `Id`
                FROM
                    `product_products` as pp
                WHERE
                    CONCAT(
                        `Id`,
                        ' ',
                        (SELECT `Name` FROM `product_brands` WHERE `Id` = pp.BrandId),
                        ' ',
                        `ModelNumber`,
                        ' ',
                        `Title`,
                        IF(`isFreeShipping` = 1 OR `isFreeShippingOnOrder` = 1, ' FreeShipping', '')
                    )
                LIKE :Title;
                ");
            $MatchingRow -> bindValue(':Title','%'.$Query.'%');
            try{
                $MatchingRow -> execute();
                foreach($MatchingRow -> fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $QueryInfo)
                    $Matchings[$Query][$QueryInfo['Id']] = $QueryInfo['Id'];
            }catch(\PDOException $e){
                echo 'Error MySQL: '.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        $TmpMatch = $Matchings;
        $Matches = array_shift(array_values($TmpMatch));
        foreach($TmpMatch as $Query)
        {
            $Matches = array_intersect($Matches,$Query);
        }
        foreach($Matches as $Match){
            $Products[] = new Product($Match);
        }
        return $Products;
    }
```

Comment: Make a research on fulltext search. Your implementation is not possible to optimise (`like` with an operand starting with `%` would always case a full table scan).

Comment: [full text search in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for you comments guys, After reading, I realized that I will loose the functionallity to inject ( for FreeShipping purpuses ) Am I right to think that ?

I could work around it by simply doing the full search and then with php remove item that arent free shipping (if customer searched for it).  But is there a better way with Full Text to "Inject" text based on condition ?

Comment: Do not "inject" it - use as a separate search term.

Comment: @zerkms Thats the thing FreeShipping is a filed on the product row. meaning that FreeShipping is either 1 or 0, So the search term would have to be 1, but 1 will match all the other 1 in the full text search also.

If you look closely in the current MySQL I have at the moment I am "Injecting" FreeShipping in the title if the free shipping field is `1`

Comment: So, why do not you express it as a separate search predicate? Why would you need to "inject" it into a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have already suggested, [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) is your friend.

The logic should go more or less like this.

- Add a text column to your "product_products" table called, say, "FtSearch"
- Write a small script that will run only once, in which you write, for each existing product, the text that has to be searched for into the "FtSearch" column. This is, of course, the text you compose in your query (id + brand name + title and so forth, including the FreeShipping part). You can probably do this with a single SQL statement, but I have no mysql at hand and can't provide you the code for that... you might be able to find it out by yourself.
- Create a fulltext index on the "FtSearch" column (doing this *after* having populated the FtSearch column saves you a little execution time).
- Now you have to add the code necessary to ensure that every time any of the fields involved in the search string is inserted/updated, you insert/update the search string as well. Pay attention here, since this includes not only the "Title", "ModelNumber" and "FreeShipping" of the "product_product", but as well the "Name" of the "product_brand". This means that if the name of a product_brand is updated, you will have to regenerate all search strings of all products having that brand. This might be a little slow, depending on how many products are bound to that brand. However I assume it does not happen too often that a brand changes its name, and if it does, it certainly happens in some sort of administration interface where such things are usually acceptable.
- At this point you can query the table using the `MATCH` construct, which is way way faster you could ever get by using your current approach.

Comment: Cool, It does search much faster. (0.05~Sec) But also, it can easily botleneck the DEDICATED server... lol. If the search words are too general. I am searching with the following syntax `match(`ftSearch`) against (+firstWord* +otherword* IN BOOLEAN MODE)
Any recomentation ?

Comment: A few:
 - If it is a live search while the user is typing, you can probably avoid the `*` at the end of all words except the last one (which is still being typed). 
 - Secondly, start searching when the user has typed in at least 2 chars. 
 - And last but not least, avoid doing many many calls: do a query only if the user has typed in a new letter and even then, set a small timeout (200 ms or so) in case the user types in further letters, and only do a search when the timeout has passed since the last typed character.